# Infinite Scrolling with a strange bug

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I got on the internet a infinite scrolling script, however it was in jQuery... and since I don't like jquery, I decided to change it to pure JS.
When I replaced this **$(window).on** for this **window.addEventListener** and this
**$(window).off("scroll");** for this **window.removeEventListener("scroll",...** and a bug appeared:

Code running with jQuery - working very well:

```
<div class="post-item" id="8">8</div>
<div class="post-item" id="7">7</div>
<div class="post-item" id="6">6</div>
<div class="post-item" id="5">5</div>
<div class="post-item" id="4">4</div>
<div class="post-item" id="3">3</div>
<div class="post-item" id="2">2</div>
<div class="post-item" id="1">1</div>

windowOnScroll();
function windowOnScroll() {
  $(window).on("scroll", function(e){
    const {scrollHeight,scrollTop,clientHeight} = document.documentElement
    if (scrollTop + clientHeight > scrollHeight -5){
      if(document.querySelectorAll(".post-item").length < document.getElementById("total_count").value) {
        var lastId = document.querySelectorAll(".post-item");
        var lastchild = lastId[lastId.length-1];
        var id=lastchild.getAttribute("id");
        getMoreData(id);
      }
    }
  });
}
function getMoreData(id) {
  $(window).off("scroll");
  document.querySelector('.ajax-loader').classList.remove("none");
  var formdata=new FormData();
  formdata.append("lastId",id);
  fetch('getMoreData.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    body:formdata
  }).then(function(response){
    response.text().then(function(result){
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('.ajax-loader').classList.add("none");
        document.getElementById("post-list").innerHTML+=result;
        windowOnScroll();
      }, 1000);
    })
  }).catch(function(err){ 
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

Code running with JS pure - working NOT very well:

```
<div class="post-item" id="8">8</div>
<div class="post-item" id="7">7</div>
<div class="post-item" id="6">6</div>
<div class="post-item" id="5">5</div>
<div class="post-item" id="4">4</div>
<div class="post-item" id="3">3</div>
<div class="post-item" id="2">2</div>
<div class="post-item" id="4">4</div>
<div class="post-item" id="3">3</div>
<div class="post-item" id="2">2</div>
<div class="post-item" id="4">4</div>
<div class="post-item" id="3">3</div>
<div class="post-item" id="2">2</div>

windowOnScroll();
function windowOnScroll() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
    const {scrollHeight,scrollTop,clientHeight} = document.documentElement
    if (scrollTop + clientHeight > scrollHeight -5){
      if(document.querySelectorAll(".post-item").length < document.getElementById("total_count").value) {
        var lastId = document.querySelectorAll(".post-item");
        var lastchild = lastId[lastId.length-1];
        var id=lastchild.getAttribute("id");
        getMoreData(id);
      }
    }
  });
}
function getMoreData(id) {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", windowOnScroll());
  document.querySelector('.ajax-loader').classList.remove("none");
  var formdata=new FormData();
  formdata.append("lastId",id);
  fetch('getMoreData.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    body:formdata
  }).then(function(response){
    response.text().then(function(result){
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('.ajax-loader').classList.add("none");
        document.getElementById("post-list").innerHTML+=result;
        windowOnScroll();
      }, 1000);
    })
  }).catch(function(err){ 
    console.error(err);
  });
```

I'm using MYSQL and PHP on the server side.

Any idea to help me???

[DEMO](https://booge.com.br/lab/)

Comment: Can you possibly provide some code to the JavaScript, as the information that you did provide isn't enough to really help. After all, you expect us to help when you don't provide any sort of code to the problem area, that isn't how things work, we won't be able to help without having the code.

Comment: @OfficerErikK I put the code on my website. https://booge.com.br/lab/ access it by desktop and view the bug in element inspector on your favorite browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the problem was not that.. try this now, I added logic to not make other call until it finishes loading.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>How to Create Facebook Like Infinite Scroll Pagination using PHP and jQuery</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: Arial;
        background: #e9ebee;
        font-size: 0.9em;
      }

      .post-wall {
        background: #fff;
        border: #e0dfdf 1px solid;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 500px;
      }

      .post-item {
        padding: 10px;
        border: #f3f3f3 1px solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }

      .post-title {
        color: #4faae6;
      }

      .ajax-loader {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .none {
        display: none;
      }
      .ajax-loader img {
        width: 50px;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="post-wall">
      <div id="post-list">
        <input type="hidden" name="total_count" id="total_count" value="22" />

        <div class="post-item" id="22">
          <p class="post-title">Ajax live search using jQuery Ajax and PHP</p>
          <p>Ajax live search is a search form where you get search results instantly while you type. Therefore i</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post-item" id="21">
          <p class="post-title">Live image preview before upload to the server using jQuery</p>
          <p>Sometimes it is required to verify the selected image before upload it to the server. So, in this tu</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post-item" id="20">
          <p class="post-title">Count words and characters using jQuery</p>
          <p>A simple, word and character counter for HTML textarea and other input fields. The following simple</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post-item" id="19">
          <p class="post-title">Write data into CSV file using PHP</p>
          <p>Sometimes we need to generate CSV file containing data from database table. So, in this tutorial, we</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post-item" id="18">
          <p class="post-title">Read CSV file using PHP</p>
          <p>Read CSV file using PHP is very easy and simple. PHP has a built function fgetcsv(), through which w</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ajax-loader none text-center"><img src="LoaderIcon.gif" /> Loading more posts...</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var isLoading = false;

      window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;
        if (
          scrollTop + clientHeight > scrollHeight - 5 &&
          document.querySelectorAll(".post-item").length < document.getElementById("total_count").value
        ) {
          var lastId = document.querySelectorAll(".post-item");
          var lastchild = lastId[lastId.length - 1];
          var id = lastchild.getAttribute("id");
          getMoreData(id);
        }
      });

      function getMoreData(id) {
        if (isLoading) return;

        isLoading = true;

        document.querySelector(".ajax-loader").classList.remove("none");
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("lastId", id);
        fetch("getMoreData.php", {
          method: "POST",
          body: formdata,
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            response.text().then(function (result) {
              setTimeout(function () {
                document.querySelector(".ajax-loader").classList.add("none");
                document.getElementById("post-list").innerHTML += result;
                isLoading = false;
              }, 1000);
            });
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
            isLoading = false;
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```